# Low priority job in node.js

Tags: javascript, multithreading, node.js

Based on the fact that node uses a single thread to manage everything, I am curious how I should go about handling a low-priority job

This job is constantly running and analyzing data (let's say it is a `setTimeout`), but what it does takes a lot of time, and I want it to have a really low priority in the scheduler.

I don't think I can run it in a separate process, because I need to modify its working instructions really often (it works using the variables of my main process, so it needs to be able to access them constantly).

You can imagine this as a big stack of tasks, that it will constantly work on, but the working set for these tasks is controlled by the main process.

- A separate process would need constant requests between the two to exchange data, so that seems like a bad idea
- A separate thread, like a web worker, may be faster at that? I don't know if node supports them though
- The best thing would be for it to be a simple event function running on a timer, which respects the principles of node, but I need to somehow tell the scheduler to spend less time on this function than on the rest of the program. Is there any way of doing it?

Comment: Have a look at [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/). Inter-Process communication is lightning-fast.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all let me start by saying:

### This *is* a big problem.

In general, running "background tasks" in a single threaded environment is problematic for obvious reasons.

Let's start from the end, your third approach.

#### Using a function with a timer:

Running a second function with a timer sounds nice, but how would it know if the time ended?

You can do something like:

```
function myFunc(){
    var date = Date.now();
    while(date - Date.now() < 5 || nothingElseToDo()) { // 5 miliseconds
         // do something
    }
    setImmediate(myFunc); // continue processing after event loop did a cycle
}
```

However, that's not really effective or precise, and 5 milliseconds is *a lot*.

#### What about your second approach, a thread?

Alternatively, you can use [threads](https://github.com/xk/node-threads-a-gogo) with threads_a_gogo which seems to fit your use case very well for creating background threads.

#### NOTE: this is not a viable example, threads_a_gogo does not work in node 0.10.x

They have an elaborate example (I'm copying here) on GitHub showing how to use threads with an event emitter:

**quickIntro_evented_childThreadCode.js**

// This is the code that's .load()ed into the child/background thread:

```
function fibo (n) {
    return n > 1 ? fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2) : 1;
}

thread.on('giveMeTheFibo', function onGiveMeTheFibo (data) {
    this.emit('theFiboIs', fibo(+data)); //Emits 'theFiboIs' in the parent/main thread.
});
```

**main file:**

```
var thread= require('threads_a_gogo').create();
thread.load(__dirname + '/quickIntro_evented_childThreadCode.js');

//Emit 'giveMeTheFibo' in the child/background thread.
thread.emit('giveMeTheFibo', 35);

//Listener for the 'theFiboIs' events emitted by the child/background thread.
thread.on('theFiboIs', function cb (data) {
  process.stdout.write(data);
  this.emit('giveMeTheFibo', 35);
});

(function spinForever () {
  process.stdout.write(".");
  process.nextTick(spinForever);
})();
```

This sort of event emitter, with the main application shooting events to a thread nice for your use case.

#### What I'd do:

Neither, I'd write all the data I need to crunch in the background into a concurrent queue on some data store (probably redis) and perform writes there from NodeJS asynchronously, Then I'd read them with my 'task' code (process, yes) for performing these tasks.

That way, it's clear that this task is not really a part of the normal server flow.

Comment: Agreed.  It's nice to try to keep things simple and integrated, but usually trying to force something to be simpler than it really is backfires.  Instead, design a way to run low-priority jobs.

Comment: @Brandon absolutely agreed - which is why I'd use something like https://github.com/learnboost/kue myself which supports priorities (but didn't want to suggest a heavy library like this heads up). Do you have any idea why the answer was down voted -_-?

Comment: This seems like a nice way of doing it. I'm just wondering, what is the cost of emitting between threads like this? Is it similar to a function call or is there a drawback? I may need to do it really often in some cases

Comment: Using threads doesn't have much sense since you can't share state between them.

Comment: @Malharhak using threads is considerably slower than callbacks, yes - note that you'll only be creating one additional thread here. Also worth noting that emitting the data to an external queue is likely the best approach here if you ever intend to put this in a production environment.

Comment: The solution is definitely what you say: use another app and use something to communicate between them.

Comment: @vkurchatkin generally, you can share data between threads. Even if you couldn't - they're still a lighter than processes (on some operating systems the difference is more prevalent). Sharing data explicitly between threads is risky though and an event emitter seems to make much more sense here.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum how is it possible? no observable API for that. Moreover, using threads involves creating new `v8::Isolate` and you can't share objects between isolates as far as I know.

Comment: After a little bit of thinking I can probably manage to keep the exchange volume lower than I initially thought. But I'm still wondering what the action of emitting to the thread costs, compared to calling a function.

Comment: @vkurchatkin Note my 'generally' there about threads. You're completely correct that `threads_a_gogo` uses `::isolate` so explicit state sharing between threads is impossible (well, _very_ hard) (with threads_a_gogo, not with v8 in general).

Comment: @Malharhak if you are ok with passing data via messages another process is best choice. You can't using things like `threads_a_gogo` in production. It doesn't even work on current versions of node.

Comment: @vkurchatkin I'm the one who upvoted that comment. I don't think using a thread is the correct choice either. I think that's what my answer says too "hat I'd do:

Neither, I'd write all the data I need to crunch in the background into a concurrent queue on some data store (probably redis) and perform writes there from NodeJS asynchronously, Then I'd read them with my 'task' code (process, yes) for performing these tasks.". If you think that bit wasn't clear enough I'll gladly clarify that in my answer.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum your answer is ok in general, but there is just too much about threads, so there is a chance that people unexperienced i node would think that threads are really a thing in node, which they are not. Moreover `threads_a_gogo` simply doesn't work on 0.10.x and thing like `spinForever` from the example causes infinite recursion.

Comment: @vkurchatkin Fair enough, disclaimer added.